# TkzDrawAltitude no longer works, with 'Paragraph ended before \tkz@Altitude' error

Tags: tikz-pgf

One of the sections of my book draws out the dot product. The code below has worked fine for years. I'm now on Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest texlive and pgf packages, and the same command below now fails... has one of the relevant packages been updated with new syntax? Any help appreciated

Fails now, but always worked fine (minimum working example, extract):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}% should be removed

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\node[circle,fill=black,draw,black,scale=0.2] (a) at (2,2) {};
\node[circle,fill=black,draw,black,scale=0.2] (O) at (0,0) {};
\node[circle,fill=black,draw,black,scale=0.2] (b) at (3,-1) {};
\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow[black,line width=2pt]{>}}}}](O)--(a)node[midway,above]{\textbf{a}};  
\draw[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow[black,line width=2pt]{>}}}}](O)--(b)node[midway,below]{\textbf{b}};  
\draw pic [draw=red,fill=red!20,angle radius=4mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle = b--O--a};

\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](O,b)(a)
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](P){$P$}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(a,P,O) 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example complete/compilable so that others can simply copy, paste, and compile it without adding any missing lines.

Comment: Thank you, I've turned it into a MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution with only `tkz-euclide`. I used the version 4 where `tkzDrawAltitude` no longer exists. Now you need to use `tkzdefSpeTriangle[orthic](a,O,b){...}`to get the feet of the altitudes. Then you continue with `\tkzDrawLines`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\tkzDefPoints{2/2/a,3/-1/b,0/0/O}
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.2 with  {\arrow[black,line width=1pt]{>}}}]
 \tkzDrawSegments[postaction={decorate}](O,a O,b) 
\end{scope}
% v4
\tkzDefSpcTriangle[orthic](a,O,b){P,HO,Hb}
\tkzDrawLine[dashed,color=magenta](a,P)
% v 3.06 \tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](O,a,b)
\tkzLabelPoint[below](P){$P$}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(a,P,O) 
\tkzDrawPoints(a,b,O)

\tkzFillAngle[fill=red!20,opacity=.5,size=.5](b,O,a)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.4](b,O,a){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this reply too

Answer (score 4):

Somehow, `tkz-euclide` has changed (perhaps since v3.01c released on January 25, 2020) the syntax of `\tkzDrawAltitude`
from (see [source code lines](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-polygons.tex?limit_changes=0&view=markup&pathrev=53530#l216))

```tex
\tkzDrawAltitude[<options>](A,B)(C)
```

to (see source code lines on texlive SVN repo, `` added and `tikz-euclide` GitHub repo)

```
\tkzDrawAltitude[<options>](A,C,B)
```

Some notes

- the old syntax is [implemented in `tkz-obj-polygons.tex`](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-polygons.tex?limit_changes=0&view=markup&pathrev=53530#l216) which lasted in texlive's SVN repo [from revision 22830 (Jun 6 2011) to 53530](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-obj-polygons.tex?limit_changes=0&view=log&pathrev=53530), and is deleted in   revision 53531 (Jan 24 2020).
- the new syntax is [implemented in `tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines.tex`](https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-euclide/blob/5f6e8a35f20da851f9ec390f29939e270da4950a/latex/tkz-obj-eu-draw-lines.tex#L68-L77), which is added to texlive in revision 53531.

---

Hence in OP's example, changing

```tex
\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](O,b)(a)
% to
\tkzDrawAltitude[dashed,color=magenta](O,a,b)
```

fixes the problem.

Moreover,

- in the latest (v3.06c) doc of `tkz-euclide`, the only one documented way to draw altitude is

  ```tex
  \tkzDrawLine[altitude,<options>](A,C,B)
  ```
- and `\usetkzobj{all}` should be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this; I can confirm this solved the problem and my document once again compiles successfully. Your help is very much appreciated.